# Activate object that have button component?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to activate the array object that have button component.

```
 public GameObject[] weapon_carry_pistol = new GameObject[3];
 public int p1_carry,activeObjects;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
{

  p1_carry =  weapon_carry_pistol[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Button>().Length; // 6 objects

        for (int i = 0; i < activeObjects; i++)
    {
        weapon_carry_pistol[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()[i].enabled = true;
    }

}
```

This script do activate the button component but not the whole game object. If I change "Button" to "GameObject" I get error //.GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.//

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual difference between a GameObject and a Component. One GameObject has many Components and every Component belongs to a GameObject. If you have that thing on the UI which you consider a button, then what you actually have is a GameObject which has a Button component (among other components).

Some components can be enabled and disabled with a `.enabled` property or in some other way (not all components, though. For example, you can disable a `Renderer` but you can't disable a `Transform`). A GameObject on the other hand, is activated or deactivated with the [`SetActive(bool)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) method.

So if you want to get all the game objects in the children of `weapon_carry_pistol[0]` which have a button and then activate those game objects, then you:

1. find all the button-components with `GetComponentsInChildren`. In this case you specifically want to include any buttons in inactive game objects, so you need to use `GetComponentsInChildren<Button>(true)`.
2. iterate those in a [`foreach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop
3. determine the GameObject of the current button by checking the [`.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) property every component has.
4. activate that GameObject with `.SetActive(true)`

Like this:

```
foreach (Button button in weapon_carry_pistol[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Button>(true) ) {
   button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Still something is missing. Here is the new [script now] (https://hastebin.com/yukepitaqo.cs). The issue now that when I increase "activeObjects" one value all objects with button active or not show up !!

Comment: @user43474 I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you add more information about what exactly you want to do, how your object hierarchy looks? Why is `weapon_carry_pistol` an array anyway and what does `activeObjects`mean? It's hard to tell what exactly you need when you don't show us the full picture.

Comment: (https://i.postimg.cc/52KCnDqm/00.png) As you see on image, there is a parent and 6 child objects. In my script, "weapon_carry_pistol" is the parent object. That's why i'm using "GetComponentsInChildren" to get child objects inside my array and activate them by numbers. If activeObjects = 1. the first element in my array will be active. and so on. I tried "GameObject" instead "button" but I got error !!